# Circle Sector Area Calculation - I am getting wrong answer

Tags: plane-geometry, calculator

I am trying to calculate the area of a *circle segment* using MS-Excel. The radius value is stored in variable "rr", the angle is stored in variable "a".

There are 2 equivalent formulas, depending on whether the angle is in digress or radians, that should yield the same results, but in my case, I am getting different results.

Formula 1 gives:$57.345$ - I think this is the correct one...

Formula 2 gives:$303.025$

Where are my mistake in Formula $2$? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: [SIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sin-function-cf0e3432-8b9e-483c-bc55-a76651c95602) expects an argument in radians, so even in formula 2 it should still be `SIN(RADIANS(a))`.

Comment: @peterwhy, Super answer. Please make it an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sin-function-cf0e3432-8b9e-483c-bc55-a76651c95602) expects an argument in radians, so even in formula 2 it should still be `SIN(RADIANS(a))`.

Comment: I appreciate your help.